# Navigating XML from Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, xml

I'm getting this XML response from TwitPic:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <rsp stat="ok">
        <mediaid>abc123</mediaid>
        <mediaurl>http://twitpic.com/abc123</mediaurl>
    </rsp>
```

I want to access the value within the 'mediaurl' tags.

So I tried:

```
NSString *twitpicURL = [[request responseHeaders] objectForKey:@"mediaurl"];
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Can someone point me in the right direction with this please?

Thanks,

Jamie.

Answer (score 3):

Apple has [NSXMLDocument](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (available on Mac OS X only) and [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (available on Mac OS X and iPhone) both are based on the open source C library [Libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/index.html) (available on Mac OS X and iPhone).

If you decide to use NSXMLDocument I would suggest using [XPath](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/NSXML_Concepts/Articles/QueryingXML.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001258) as a quick/simple way to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

CoreFoundation has a library for parsing xml.

http://developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFXML/CFXML.html

if you are not developing for the apple platform, expat is a well known C XML parser :)

http://expat.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

I realize you asked this a couple days ago but I thought I'd give you an example of how to use NSXMLParser. I don't remember where I learned this from but this is the technique I've used on my projects.

You could either create your own class like this one and instantiate it after your network call ends and call the "parseData:" function, or simply paste all this mumbo jumbo into the class that handles the network code and call the function from there.

```
#import "ThaweExampleParser.h"

@interface ThaweExampleParser() <NSXMLParserDelegate>
@property (nonatomic) BOOL accumulatingParsedCharacterData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString *currentParsedCharacterData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *parsedContents;
@end

@implementation ThaweExampleParser

@synthesize accumulatingParsedCharacterData;
@synthesize currentParsedCharacterData;
@synthesize parsedContents;

/*
 *  This function you would call when your network connection finishes.
 *  You pass in the NSMutableData you collected during the request.
 */

- (void)parseData:(NSData *)webData
{
    self.currentParsedCharacterData = [NSMutableString string];
    self.parsedContents = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:webData];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
}

/*
 *  The parsed calls this function everytime it finds a new tag.
 *  A tag looks like "<mediaurl>"
 *  So in this case we want to turn or BOOL to YES so that the last function collects only the characters we care about.
 */

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"mediaurl"])
    {
        self.accumulatingParsedCharacterData = YES;
        [self.currentParsedCharacterData setString:@""];
    }
}

/* 
 *  Much the previous function except the tag looks like "</mediaurl>"
 *  Turn our BOOL to NO because we are done collecting characters for the moment.
 *  We also are saving the important data to a dictionary so that you can use it later.
 */

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"mediaurl"])
    {
        self.accumulatingParsedCharacterData = NO;
        [self.parsedContents setObject:[self.currentParsedCharacterData copy] forKey:elementName];
    }
}

/*
 *  The parser calls this function everytime it finds characters.
 *  In your case it would call it maybe 5 or 6 times with data that you dont want to collect.
 *  So we use a BOOL to control what we collect;
 */

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{
    if (self.accumulatingParsedCharacterData) [self.currentParsedCharacterData appendString:string];
}

@end
```