# xml paeser for iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have a xml file on a server that look for example like this one:

```
<breakfast_menu>
    <food>
        <name>Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$5.95</price>
        <description>two of our famous Belgian Waffles with plenty of real maple        syrup</description>
        <calories>650</calories>
    </food>
    <food>
        <name>Strawberry Belgian Waffles</name>
        <price>$7.95</price>
        <description>light Belgian waffles covered with strawberries and whipped        cream</description>
        <calories>900</calories>
    </food>
</breakfast_menu>
```

i need xml parser that will parse it and enter each one of them to a class that for examle will called food(and have 4 parameters : name,price,.....).
and finally to create an array of the classes that he create.there is built xml parser that do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some sources on the topic:

- [Navigating XML from Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/762567/402706)
- [How do I parse an NSString containing XML in Objective-C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/924389/402706)
- [Objective C: Parsing an XML file](http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2010/08/04/objective-c-parsing-an-xml-file/)
- [Parsing XML in Cocoa](http://weblog.bignerdranch.com/?p=48)
- [Parsing XML in objective-c](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=244288)

Answer (score 0):

For learning to parse xml, look at the links Brandon provided.  Your requirement to build an array of classes from xml is something you'll need to create yourself.

A suggestion I have for you is instead of creating classes, just put the data into a `NSMutableArray`.  The array will contain `NSDictionary` objects for food sub-items.