# XML Parser objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, parsing

I have a xml to parse:

```
<media:content url='http://www.youtube.com/v/x5cBBXXFAPQ?version=3&amp;f=playlists&amp;app=youtube_gdata' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' medium='video' isDefault='true' expression='full' duration='391' yt:format='5'/><media:content url='rtsp://r5---sn-4g57kuee.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAn0AMV1BQGXxxMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='391' yt:format='1'/><media:content url='rtsp://r5---sn-4g57kuee.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAn0AMV1BQGXxxMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='391' yt:format='6'/><media:description type='plain'>Bohemian Rhapsody
```

how can i get the first url from content ?

Comment: Id say: what have you tried, this is too broad, SO isn't meant as a 'write my code for me' kind of page... but I don't.. Instead I give you the code

Comment: possible duplicate of [Navigating XML from Objective-C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/762567/navigating-xml-from-objective-c)

Answer (score 0):

runnable sample:
edited based on comment...

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MyClass : NSObject<NSXMLParserDelegate>
@end
@implementation MyClass

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    id xml = @"<media:content url='http://www.youtube.com/v/x5cBBXXFAPQ?version=3&amp;f=playlists&amp;app=youtube_gdata' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' medium='video' isDefault='true' expression='full' duration='391' yt:format='5'/><media:content url='rtsp://r5---sn-4g57kuee.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAn0AMV1BQGXxxMYDSANFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='391' yt:format='1'/><media:content url='rtsp://r5---sn-4g57kuee.c.youtube.com/CiULENy73wIaHAn0AMV1BQGXxxMYESARFEgGUglwbGF5bGlzdHMM/0/0/0/video.3gp' type='video/3gpp' medium='video' expression='full' duration='391' yt:format='6'/><media:description type='plain'>Bohemian Rhapsody";
    id d = [xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSXMLParser *p = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:d];
    p.delegate = self;
    [p parse];

    return self;
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {
    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"media:content"]) {
        static BOOL first = YES;
        if(first) {
             NSLog(@"%@", attributeDict[@"url"]);
             first = NO;
        }
    }
}

@end

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        id c = [[MyClass alloc] init];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this is worked for all url which i have , but i want only for the first url from content :(

Comment: how about just only save the first one then? ;)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to refer the Apple Documention

[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/index.html](http://NSXMLParser)

```
- (void)viewDidLoad

   {
      NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc]initWithString:@"yourURL"];
        NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:url];
        [parser setDelegate:self];
       BOOL result = [parser parse];
   }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
    {
        NSLog(@\"Did start element\");
    if ( [elementName isEqualToString:@"media:content"])
     {
        NSLog(@"found URL",[attributeDict objectForKey:@"url"]);//here u will get the url u want
        return;
    }
    }

    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
    {
        NSLog(@"Did end element");
        if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"media"]) 
            {
              NSLog(@"rootelement end");
            }

    }
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
    {

           NSLog(@"Value %@",string);

    }
```

It just overview about the delegate methods of XML not the solution..Refer the Document..